# add two column in product choose grid in widget

Tags: magento-1.9, widget

[image: I want to add two column describe in image]

**I want to add two column describe in image**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by rewriting the below class
`Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Widget_Chooser`

And rewrite this class's two method `prepareCollection` and `prepareColumns`